# Regular Expression in Atom Text Editor, exclude string "abc" from beginning of string

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I have some code as follows:

```
data[:value] = some_val
data[:value_two] = someval2
data[:total_value_three] = someval3
```

I want to replace all code where total is not included,
I want the following result:

```
data[:total_value] = some_val
data[:total_value_two] = someval2
data[:total_value_three] = someval3
```

I have lot of such code in the text editor,
to replace that I have used this regular expression:

```
\[:[^total]([A-z_0-9]*)\]
```

And I am replacing it with this:

```
[:total_$1]
```

It is selecting the right data, but it is removing the first character, that is, it is becoming `total_alue` instead of `total_value`.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a Ruby tag. Isn't this just about using a regex in an editor. The fact that the text may be Ruby code seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is negative look ahead. You can write it as

```
\[:(?!total)([A-z_0-9]*)\]
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/UTOWyJ/2)

- `(?!total)` This is a negative look ahead. It checks whether `:` is **not** followed by a `total`.

---

**What is wrong in `[:[^total]([A-z_0-9]*)\]`?**

- `[^total]` This is a negated character class. What it matches is one character, which is not `t` or `o` or `a` or `l`.